# Cannot install/manage extensions due to 403: Access to the Joomla! installer is disabled

Tags: extensions, administrator, jinstaller

I'm trying to install extensions and plugins on my site, but when I hit the Extensions > Install/Manage buttons, I keep getting a message that says:

> 403: Access Forbidden, Access to the Joomla! installer is disabled.

I'm the website administrator, so I'm confused as to why this is happening.

How do I enable the Joomla installer?